# IndexError: list index out of range Python Line 36

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range

```
import math

with open("input.txt", "r") as file:
    list = []
    for line in file:
        list += [line.strip()]

list1 = list[0].split(" ")
a = int(list1[0])
b = int(list1[1])

list2 = []
list3 = []
d = a + 1
c = 1

for i in range(1, a+1):
    list2.append(list[c])
    c = c + 1

for i in range(d+1, a+b+2):
    list3.append(list[d])
    d = d + 1

e = 0
f = 0
g = 1000000000000000
list6 = []

for i in range(0, b):
    for i in range(1, a):
        list4 = list3[e].split(" ")
        x = int(list4[0])
        y = int(list4[1])

        list5 = list2[f].split(" ")
        x1 = int(list5[0])
        y1 = int(list5[1])

        distance = math.sqrt(math.pow((x1 - x), 2) + math.pow((y1 - y), 2))
        list4.clear()
        list5.clear()
        f = f + 1
        if distance < g:
            g = distance
    e = e + 1
    list6.append(g)

print(list6)
```

When I start the program, I always get "IndexError: list index out of range". Can someone help me fix the problem. The error is in line 36.

```
list5 = list2[f].split(" ")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I get : `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.txt'`

Comment: @rv.kvetch why do you think that would be? probably because you don't have that file

Comment: yeah, the thing is that I give my code a specific input through a textfile. The Input is:

12 3
-82 -315
248 714
1202 907
226 680
694 -20
-767 44
-245 719
-339 36
473 406
863 -290
953 885
-109 510
1242 -593
-1223 -1479
1720 401

Comment: @xlePyrex please [edit] your question and add the sample data there, also the error is pretty self-explanatory, you are trying to access an index of a list which doesn't have that many items in it, also exactly what are you even trying to do with those numbers? what should be the _"end product"_?

Comment: In all seriousness, the error is probably self explanatory. List index out of range can only happen in your case where `list2[f]` and `f=0` from earlier, so likely case is `list2` is an empty list

Comment: list2 isnt empty, it contains 12 items as it should

Comment: oh, I see. I missed that `f = f + 1` and the fact that its run in a loop

Comment: btw that can also be `f += 1` in case it's helpful

Comment: @Matiiss yeah... I shouldve but Its a problem from a contest which I already solved logicwhise... I just dont get why the programm tells me that the list index is out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never reset `f`. Since it is in a nested loop it will continue to grow even after the first full execution of the inner loop. Try resetting it to default at the top of the first loop:

```
import math

with open("input.txt", "r") as file:
    list = []
    for line in file:
        list += [line.strip()]

list1 = list[0].split(" ")
a = int(list1[0])
b = int(list1[1])

list2 = []
list3 = []
d = a + 1
c = 1

for i in range(1, a+1):
    list2.append(list[c])
    c = c + 1

for i in range(d+1, a+b+2):
    list3.append(list[d])
    d = d + 1

e = 0
g = 1000000000000000
list6 = []

for i in range(0, b):
    f = 0
    for i in range(1, a):
        list4 = list3[e].split(" ")
        x = int(list4[0])
        y = int(list4[1])

        list5 = list2[f].split(" ")
        x1 = int(list5[0])
        y1 = int(list5[1])

        distance = math.sqrt(math.pow((x1 - x), 2) + math.pow((y1 - y), 2))
        list4.clear()
        list5.clear()
        f = f + 1
        if distance < g:
            g = distance
    e = e + 1
    list6.append(g)

print(list6)
```